# Detecting Firebase user change with useEffect vs onAuthStateChanged - what's the difference?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm using the firebase NPM package with Next.JS/React/Typescript. From what I can tell, there are two ways of watching when a user changes:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // do something
}, [firebase.auth().currentUser])
```

and something like

```js
const onAuthStateChanged = () => {
  return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    // do something
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged();
  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  };
}, [])
```

What's the difference here? They both seem to just watch the currentUser; is one preferable over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will run everytime currentUser changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // do something
}, [firebase.auth().currentUser])
```

This only runs the first time your component mounted. You create a listener to handle changes and remove it when component unmounted.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged();
  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  };
}, [])
```

Comment: So do the first useEffect and the listener from the second one effectively do the same thing or am I misunderstanding how listeners/useEffect works?

Comment: useEffect is a special hook that react provides for user to execute things after component render. The firebase.auth(). listener has nothing to do with React render (unless you setState in your listener handler)